# How to auto approve Salesforce REST API OAuth2 authorization flow to not show "Allow Access" pop-up

Tags: oauth2

Currently, I am using OAuth2 authorization code flow to authenticate REST services, but when i am doing request to get authorization code like

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=3MVG9IHf89I1t8hrvswazsWedXWY0i1qK20PSFaInvUgL&redirect_uri=https://www.mycustomerorderstatus.com/oauth2/callback&response_type=code

But it required the login & allow access then it redirects to my callback URL with accessCode. So I want to skip this process & auto-approve it because I am using it as background service & not interacting with the user.

So how to auto-approve Salesforce REST API OAuth2 authorization_code flow to not show allow pop-up.

Comment: No. Actually i am not using JWT approach for authentication